# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

I created a maven project using Eclipse. It works fine on my computer but my colleague cannot run it while he has the same config as me (JDK version (1.8), maven version, Windows 10, Eclipse config, etc).

Here is the pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <xauthFile>authFile.txt</xauthFile> 
              <packageName>*some package name*</packageName>
              <wsdlUrls>
                <wsdlUrl>*some wsdl url*</wsdlUrl>
              </wsdlUrls>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And here are the errors :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\lgautrais\Documents\Projet\Sas-to-ips\workspace\sas-to-ips\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport (default) @ test ---
[INFO] Processing: *some wsdl url*
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.300 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-12T10:31:42+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport (default) on project test: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

and :

```
Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport failed. (org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport:default:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsimport failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.GlobalBuildAction$1.run(GlobalBuildAction.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.getSelectedVersion(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:363)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.isArgSupported(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:335)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.getCommonArgs(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:277)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.WsImportMojo.getWsImportArgs(WsImportMojo.java:379)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.WsImportMojo.processWsdlViaUrls(WsImportMojo.java:362)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.WsImportMojo.executeJaxws(WsImportMojo.java:291)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.MainWsImportMojo.executeJaxws(MainWsImportMojo.java:54)
```

We tried to install / uninstall some plugins, dependency versions but none of these worked. Do you have any idea about this problem ?

Thank you in advance for your returns.

Comment: Can you run it yourself from a shell - `mvn clean install`? If that works, take a look at your environment, and then run the same test on your colleagues machine and if you get different results compare their environment to yours.

Comment: It worked for me but not for my colleague. What do you mean by 'environment' ? The traces are the same (maven-clean-plugin:2.5 and jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5) until he gets an error

Comment: Well, he solved it by removing all the folders into the .m2/repository folder. Thank you for your help !